# Searching through HTML pages for certain text?

Tags: python, html, screen-scraping

I wanted to play around with python to learn it, so I'm taking on a little project, but a part of it requires me to search for a name on this list:

https://bughunter.withgoogle.com/characterlist/1

(the number one is to be incremented by one every time to search for the name)

So I will be HTML scraping it, I'm new to python and would appreciate if someone could give me an example of how to make this work.

Comment: try [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Taking a look, thanks. Could someone provide an example tho?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://bughunter.withgoogle.com'


def get_page_html(page_num):
    r = requests.get('{}/characterlist/{}'.format(URL, page_num))
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.text


def get_page_profiles(page_html):
    page_profiles = {}
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html)
    for table_cell in soup.find_all('td'):
        profile_name = table_cell.find_next('h2').text
        profile_url = table_cell.find_next('a')['href']
        page_profiles[profile_name] = '{}{}'.format(URL, profile_url)
    return page_profiles


if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_profiles = {}
    for page_number in range(1, 81):
        current_page_html = get_page_html(page_number)
        current_page_profiles = get_page_profiles(current_page_html)
        all_profiles.update(current_page_profiles)
    with open('google_hall_of_fame_profiles.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(all_profiles, f, indent=2)
```

Your question wasn't clear about how you wanted the data structured after scraping so I just saved the profiles in a dict (with the key/value pair as `{profile_name: profile_url}`) and then dumped the results to a json file.

Let me know if anything is unclear!

Comment: Hey, the code doesn't even run or give any response, any idea? I'm using python3 with bs4

Comment: @OnsAli [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) is a third-party library (like `BeautifulSoup4`) and must be installed with `pip install requests`. I just tested it again and it runs fine, the output is saved to a json file named `google_hall_of_fame_profiles.json`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting no response, here is my terminal
http://i.imgur.com/pIRSnsg.png

Comment: I think I'm not waiting before it finishes, how long should it normally take? I'm running the same cli commands you show in the video.

Comment: @OnsAli Depends on your connection, maybe a couple minutes? I left a comment below the video explaining that I only scraped the first page to save recording time. You could add a line like `print('Scraped page {} of 80!'.format(page_number))` underneath the `all_profiles.update(...)` line (in the for loop) to give yourself an idea of the progress. Just try letting it go for a few minutes.

Comment: @OnsAli No problem! The requests in this script are synchronous (one after the other) and there are ways to make it faster but I opted for simplicity  to try and keep the code clear.

Comment: I thank you for going out of your way and helping me solve the question, I have a clear cut idea of how bs works now, thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will need to install bs4 first (python 3). It will get all of the names of the people on the website page:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import urllib.request
text=str(urllib.request.urlopen('https://bughunter.withgoogle.com/characterlist/1').read())
text=soup(text)
print(text.findAll(class_='item-list')[0].get_text())
```